# QGIS & Python: creating XML metadata file: problem with namespace

Tags: pyqgis, metadata, xml

I'm writing a Python processor for QGIS. He will export data and write metadata in XML so that we can upload our "document d'urbanisme" in the "geoportail de l'urbanisme" (https://www.geoportail-urbanisme.gouv.fr/)

I used to generate the XML with SQL but I'd like to do it with Python. We got the template (XML file named fr-0000xxxxx-pluDATAPPRO.xml in the zip available here https://cnig.gouv.fr/IMG/zip/230317_gabarit_plu_cc_cnig_v2022-10.zip)

Here the code I wrote:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    def oldmetadataInspire(idurba,chemin):
        nom =  f"fr-0000{idurba[0:5]}-{idurba[6:9]}{idurba[10:]}"
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(f"nom fichier metadonnées : {nom}", 'ExportGPU', level=Qgis.MessageLevel.Info)
        
        # récupérer le modèle et renseigner les "champs" à renseigner
        tree = ET.parse("C:/Users/<user>/nvelle_arbo/projets/exp_gpu_qgis/modele_fr-0000xxxxx-pluDATAPPRO.xml")
        root = tree.getroot()
        ElementInclude.include(root)
       
        # pourquoi {http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd} ? pourquoi lors de l'écriture, on se retrouve avec <ns0:fileIdentifier> et plus <gmd:fileIdentifier>
       
        for id in root.findall('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}fileIdentifier'):
            
            for child in id:
                child.text = f"{nom}"
        
        for ds in root.findall("{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}dateStamp/*"):
            print(ds.tag, ds.attrib)
            ds.text = date.today().isoformat()
     
        for tit in root.findall("/gmd:identificationInfo/gmd:MD_DataIdentification/gmd:citation/gmd:CI_Citation/gmd:title"):
            print(tit.tag, tit.attrib)
        
        for orga in root.findall('./contact/CI_ResponsibleParty/organisationName'):
            print(orga.tag, orga.attrib)
            
        tree.write(os.path.join(chemin,f"{nom}.xml"))
```

The thing I don't get is why the file written contains `<ns0:fileIdentifier>` instead of  `<gmd:fileIdentifier>` in the template file. Why are the queries "`http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}dateStamp/`" and not "`gmd:dateStamp/`"?

What should I do? How could I write my metadata file with the proper namespace using my template file?

What did I not understand?

Comment: Use a namespace dict https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Comment: Your question isn't QGIS or pyqgis related, it's a pure python issue with the `ElementTree` module.